# Find the number of bacteria after dividing

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, word-problem

> Pink eye is an infection casued by bacteria. After you have been infected, these bacteria double every 40 minutes. How many bacteria would be present at 6 pm if a single bacterium began reproducing at 11am?

$a=1$ and $r=2$ for this geometric sequence and every $40$ min = $2 \over 3$ hrs, so I've come up with the equation

$$\begin{align}
t_n&=a(r)^{n-1} \\
t_n&=(2)^{{3\over2}(n-1)}
\end{align}$$

$7$ hours passed, so $n=8$

$$\begin{align}
t_n&=(2)^{{3\over 2}(8-1)} \\
&=2^{{3\over2}(7)} \\
&=2^{21\over2} \\
&=1448.1546
\end{align}$$

So, there will be $1448$ bacteria.

However, this is wrong. The answer is supposed to be $724$.

Why is my answer wrong? I double checked by creating a chart, and $724$ does not seem reasonable:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Time} & \text{Number of Bacteria} \\\hline
11:00 \text{ am} & 1\\\hline
11:40 \text{ am} & 2\\\hline
12:20 \text{ pm} & 4\\\hline
1:00 \text{ pm} & 8\\\hline
1:40 \text{ pm} & 16\\\hline
2:20 \text{ pm} & 32\\\hline
3:00 \text{ pm} & 64\\\hline
3:40 \text{ pm} & 128\\\hline
4:20 \text{ pm} & 256\\\hline
5:00 \text{ pm} & 512\\\hline
5:40 \text{ pm} & 1024\\\hline
6:00 \text{ pm} & \text{between }1024 \text{ and } 2048 \\\hline
6:20 \text{ pm} & 2048 \\\hline
\end{array}$$

Even at 5:40 pm, there should be more than $724$ bacteria. Was there something wrong in my solution or is the correct answer wrong?

Comment: Your answer is right. I presume the questioner made a 'fence-post' error.

Comment: Yes, a mistake 724 = 2^(19/2)

Comment: @Penguino Could you please post your comment as an answer so this question can be removed from the "Unanswered" queue?

Comment: I will add my concurrence that your table is right and the book wrong - in order to say that the question is ridiculous biology. I hate fake "real world problems" that suggest that they are applications of mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is correct until $6:00$ PM.  As I read the question the doubling is instantaneous, so at $6:00$ PM there are still $1024$ bacteria.  Neither you nor the solution manual should add up all the entries because your table shows the number of bacteria at each time after the doubling.  The answer should be $1024$ bacteria at $6:00$PM.